# Настройка редиректа в Nginx и Tomcat

Tags: spring, nginx, tomcat

Есть приложение myapp (Spring Boot 1.4.1) и соответствующий myapp.war. War деплоится в Tomcat 8.5.9 и приложение становится доступно по `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/`. Я хочу, чтобы приложение было доступно по `http://127.0.0.1:8081/`. Для этого в Nginx прописывается конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8081;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/;
    }
}
```

Страница становится доступна, но редиректы в коде:

```
ModelAndView response = ...
response.setViewName("redirect:/hello/");
```

все равно приклеивают `myapp`, то есть редирект идет на страницу `127.0.0.1:8081/myapp/hello/`.

Аналогичная ситуация и с шаблонизатором Thymeleaf. Ссылки вида  @{/hello/} преобразуются в /myapp/hello. С ним проблему можно решить через костыль @{~/hello/}. Но проблема где-то в другом месте.

Comment: это весь конфигурационный файл?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, нет, но это основная часть. Остальное - настройки буферов, кешей, сжатия и логов.

Comment: В показанном кусочке все правильно - должно работать

Comment: А у вас все ссылки начинаются с "/", т.е. они все абсолютные?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, да, все ссылки абсолютные.

Comment: Проще всего - деплоить как ROOT.war, чтобы приложение сразу откликалось на `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`. У вас есть такая возможность?

Comment: @Roman, да, возможность есть. Полный доступ к VPS. У меня задача стоит несколько сервлетов на одном Tomcat-е повесить на несколько разных доменов. Сразу несколько ROOT.war не могут быть. Что делать в таком случае?

Comment: Можно в tomcat создать несколько хостов (по одному на домен, соответственно), а в nginx не забыть сделать передачу нужного заголовка `Host` на tomcat (`proxy_set_header Host $host;`, например).

Comment: @Roman, спасибо, способ помог.

Comment: Добавил как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего не воевать с переписыванием ссылок, а деплоить приложение как `ROOT.war` (если, конечно, есть такая возможность), чтобы оно сразу откликалось на `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`.

Если при этом нужно поднять несколько приложений для разных доменов на одном tomcat, то надо в tomcat создать несколько хостов (по одному на домен, соответственно), а в nginx не забыть сделать передачу нужного заголовка `Host` на tomcat (`proxy_set_header Host $host;`, например).